# OWL and DL Reasoning: Why is Eros not beautiful?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, reasoning, pellet

I have created an ontology based on:

1. > Every person is beautiful if one of his/her parents is beautiful
2. > Aphrodite is a parent of Eros
3. > Aphrodite is beautiful

thus we would expect Eros to be beautiful too! However, the Pellet reasoner doesn't seem to infer that. If I manually put the type of Eros to successful, it will accept it, but shouldn't it infer it?

My ontology lies [here](https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/q3_so.pdf) (change the extension to .owl). I am also providing screenshots from Protege:

Class hierarchy:
[image]
Eros:
[image]
Inferred class hierarchy:
[image]

What am I missing?

---

EDIT:

I can see Eros appearing in this DL query:

```
hasParent some Beautiful
```

but not in this:

```
hasParent exactly 1 Beautiful
```

but still even if I say OK for `some`, I would expect to see Beautiful as I see Child in my 2nd picture, where Child is inferred by the reasoner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the HermiT reasoner (built-in with protege) ?

## UDPATE:

Ok, here is a new ontology I wrote based on your assignment (though, I didn't complete all sentences just the ones that suffice to infer that Eros is happy).

> For the RDF/XML syntax [see this pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/GXj7nzDk)

Now the reasoner will certainly infer that both Aphrodite and Eros are happy, although that was never asserted in the ontology above. 
Here is a DL query for Happy concept that shows the result, "notice we just query which instances belongs to `Happy` concept":

[image]

Eros is finally happy :)

[image]

Here is the same ontology in `Manchester syntax`

```
Ontology: <beautiful>


ObjectProperty: <beautiful#hasChild>


Class: <beautiful#Happy>

    EquivalentTo: 
        <beautiful#Person>
         and (<beautiful#hasChild> only <beautiful#Beautiful>),
        <beautiful#Beautiful>
         and <beautiful#Person>


Class: <beautiful#Beautiful>


Class: <beautiful#Successful>

    EquivalentTo: 
        <beautiful#Beautiful>
         and <beautiful#Successful>


Class: <beautiful#Child>


Class: <beautiful#Parent>


Class: <beautiful#Person>


Individual: <beautiful#Aphrodite>

    Types: 
        <beautiful#Beautiful>,
        <beautiful#Parent>,
        <beautiful#Person>

    Facts:  
     <beautiful#hasChild>  <beautiful#Eros>


Individual: <beautiful#Eros>

    Types: 
        <beautiful#Successful>,
        <beautiful#Person>
```

#### MORE UPDATE:

DL query on Beautiful shows Eros as Beautiful too:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer helps, see my edit, I will upvote, but the mystery of the beauty of Eros is not resolved yet! ;p

Comment: glad it did, I updated the answer hopefully it would help to solve the mystery :-)

Comment: ok that's a mess! it supposed to be beautiful not happy :/ sorry just noticed and can't redo it now.