# No children and happiness combined?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, reasoning, pellet

This question is related to this: [OWL and DL Reasoning: Why is Eros not beautiful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677096/owl-and-dl-reasoning-why-is-eros-not-beautiful)

I am trying to create an ontology with these features:

1. > Every person is happy if all his children are successful.
2. > Aphrodite is a parent of Eros.
3. > Eros is successful.

And here is what I have for Happy:

[image]

I expect Aphrodite not to be Happy, because of the Open World Assumption (she may have another child later), but what about Eros? He has no children, shouldn't he be happy?

Comment: Thanks @Link. I now have a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687045/x-doesn-t-like-anything-that-y-likes if you have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know if Eros has any children either, same assumption you used for Aphrodite. Hence Eros cannot be happy either.