# Barack doesn’t like anything that Donald likes

Tags: logic, rdf, owl, protege, reasoning

How to express:

> Barack doesn’t like anything that Donald likes.

in Protege?

---

My attempt:

I have `Barack` and `Donald` as *individuals* and `like` as a *property*, however, when clicking on `Barack`, the best I can get is:

> Barack like Donald

which is not good. Any ideas?

---

The answer appears to not be working.

Comment: Could you express stuff in sets. Say if the stuff X has is a subset/part of a subset of Y. X does not like it? I haven't used the software so can't be specific about it.

Comment: It *should* be possible, but I do not know how @Link... :/

Comment: The answer you've accepted is wrong. The statement does *not* imply that Barack likes anything. The logic is: `(x)(likes(Donald,x) -> !likes(Barack,x))`. I don't know how you say that in protege.

Comment: @MikeKinghan if you think about OWL or description logic, it might help. I will notify the answerer.

Comment: However I can't see why the answer is wrong @MikeKinghan.

Comment: `Barack doesn't like anything` implies `Barack doesn't like anything that
Donald likes`. So if `Barack doesn't like anything that Donald likes` implies  `Barack likes something` (as per answer), then `Barack doesn't like anything` implies `Barack likes something`. Which you know it doesn't. The fallacy in the answer is *The Existential Fallacy*.
You can google many accounts of it, inc. YouTube. You wish to say
that the intersection of `x:likes(Donald,x)` and `x:likes(Barack,x)` is empty, which is consistent with either or both being empty. Sorry can't help with your language/tool.

Comment: Thanks @MikeKinghan, you already helped a lot. Does the new updated answer meet your requirements though? I suspect not..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the new answer. If it is meant to mean `Barack likes only the things that are not liked by Donald`, that's still wrong. It would imply that if Donald dislikes Vladimir Putin then Barack likes Vladimir Putin. But `Barack doesn’t like anything that Donald likes` is consistent with both them disliking Vladimir Putin.

Comment: I agree @MikeKinghan, oh God I know what I want to say but I do not know how to make Protege understand.

Comment: I've been messing with it myself on the web and it strikes me as just a fiendishly difficult way to do logic :(

Comment: That's why you upvoted @MikeKinghan, I guess, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the individuals tab, where you can assert the type (not object property assertion) of an individual, you write (for Barack):

> likes only (not (inverse likes value Donald))

or

> likes only (not (inverse likes some {Donald}))

(Both are equivalent).

@MikeKinghan is insofar right as it was a slight overstatement (indeed, the statement you gave does not imply Barack liking anything). As for you not getting any interesting inferences in Protege, do not forget the open world assumption. Here is a working example, consisting of three axioms:

a1: EquivalentClasses(:PeopleDislikingMexicanBorderWall ObjectComplementOf(ObjectHasValue(:likes :MexicanBorderWall)))

a2: ClassAssertion(ObjectAllValuesFrom(:likes ObjectComplementOf(ObjectSomeValuesFrom(ObjectInverseOf(:likes) ObjectOneOf(:Donald)))) :Barack)

a3: ObjectPropertyAssertion(:likes :Donald :MexicanBorderWall)

If you add these statements, the reasoner will correctly infer that Barack is an instance of PeopleDislikingMexicanBorderWall.

Comment: I think that's it, but you mentioned `!`, where it comes into play?

Comment: Please check the comment of Mike Kinghan under my question, he claims that the answer is wrong.

Comment: And I will have to agree, since I use this in Protege and I do not get expected results. Any other attempt please? However, I am keeping the upvote, since it really helps.

Comment: I revised the answer with some clarifications.

Comment: Thank you matentzn I am not sure this works either. I also plugged in your sentence in my ontology, but it won't work. Are you sure that's your last attempt? :/ Also check the new comments under my question again.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "works". Did you try the working example? If you can clarify "working", we will help you. I saw the comments, I dont think it is useful to have a logic debate now. The implication with Vladimir Putin is simply wrong (mix up between universal and existential quantifier). Just say clearly what is not working, and we will help you.

Comment: Sorry for getting you upset. It's hard to day, I know, your answer will help.